# Raise ItemCommand in repeater from an htmlbutton

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have an htmlbutton that I have tagged to runat=server with an id and all that jazz in the itemtemplate for my repeater.  When I click it, even though CommandName is set, it doesn't raise the ItemCommand event for the repeater.

Do I need to do something specific on the htmlbutton to make that happen?

I have other server controls in the item template that work fine in this regard, so it isn't a postback/databinding issue, but I need to use the htmlbutton syntax for this control for some pretty specific reasons.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you set an OnClick handler for the htmlbutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular input button doesn't have [CommandEventHanlder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.aspx). You need Asp.net Button, ImageButton or LinkButton in order to catch CommandName inside ItemCommand.